# ReferenceField with reference to existing document

Tags: python, mongodb, reference, document, mongoengine

As far as I understood, [mongoengine's ReferenceField](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.ReferenceField) allows to pass a reference to another document stored in the DB.

So far I was able to create several documents in different collections (reduced to two in this example), which I need to reference to each other now.

As you will see below I want to pass reference of a given material when creating a new document in the regenerators collection. In the example I provided, this means to pass a reference to the document `aisi304`.

My regenerator documents are defined as follows:

```
class Regenerators(Document):
    material = ReferenceField(Materials, required=True)
```

The materials document needs to be referenced to a regenerator document and is defined like this:

```
class Materials(Document):
    title = StringField(unique=True, required=True)
```

However, the desired materials document is stored in the DB already as in this case:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("565b84dc55c40f63392ffdee"),
    "title": "aisi304"
}
```

So I tried to create a new regenerator document as follows passing the title of the material document to be referenced as a keyword argument:

```
# the passed keywords are read from json normally, but I put it in directly for the sake of readability
r = Regenerators(material="aisi304")
r.save()
```

However, the reference does not seem to be passed correctly since the regernator document stored in the DB looks like this (using mongod for debugging):

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("565b89d355c40f6355fa5f45"),
    "material": "aisi304"
}
```

I thought I would achieve something like this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("565b89d355c40f6355fa5f45"),
    "material": {
        "_id": ObjectId("565b84dc55c40f63392ffdee"),
        "title": "aisi304"
    }
}
```

In the [tutorial provided in the docs](http://docs.mongoengine.org/tutorial.html#adding-data-to-our-tumblelog) they pass a reference to a newly created document. However, this is not suitable for me since I need to reference to existing documents.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You shoud save a reference to your `Materials` object then pass it as argument to `Regenerators`

Demo

```
class Materials(Document):
    title = StringField(unique=True, required=True)

class Regenerators(Document):
    material = ReferenceField(Materials, required=True)

m = Materials(title='aisi304').save()

r = Regenerators(material=m).save()
```

Then your documents look like this:

```
> db.regenerators.find()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("565c9d110acf4510cf1f8712"),
        "material" : ObjectId("565c9cfc0acf4510cf1f8711")
}
> db.materials.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("565c9cfc0acf4510cf1f8711"), "title" : "aisi304" }
>
```

If you want to use a reference to an existing document you need to issue a query using the [`.get`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.get) method then pass it reference as argument to `Regenerators`

```
m = Materials.objects.get(title='aisi304')
r = Regenerators(material=m).save()
```