# get all colleges under university in flask_mongoengine

Tags: python, flask-restful, flask-mongoengine

> im using flask_mongoengine

**HERE'S THE COLLEGEMODEL:**

```
class collegeModel(DATABASE.Document):
    name = DATABASE.StringField(required=True)

    city = DATABASE.StringField(default = "NA")

    state = DATABASE.StringField(default="NA")

    country = DATABASE.StringField(default="NA")

    university = DATABASE.ReferenceField(UniversityModel,required=True)

    timestamp = DATABASE.DateTimeField(default = datetime.datetime.now())
```

**HERE'S THE UNIVERSITYMODEL:**

```
class UniversityModel(DATABASE.Document):
    name = DATABASE.StringField(required = True)

    city = DATABASE.StringField()

    state = DATABASE.StringField()

    country = DATABASE.StringField()

    timestamp = DATABASE.DateTimeField(default = datetime.datetime.now())
```

*what I'm trying to do is fetching all colleges under a particular university**

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/34006348/6505847

Comment: yeah I appreciate it, thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

```
colModel = collegeModel.objects.filter(university=universityid)
            data = json.loads(colModel.to_json())
            return {
                'status': 'success',
                'msg': f'SUCCESFULLY FETCHED THE COLLEGES UNDER UNIVERSITY: {UniversityModel.objects.get(id=universityid).name}',
                'data': data
            }
```

> collegeModel.objects.filter(university=universityid)